# applying filters to html file using maven

Tags: maven, ant, properties, pom.xml

I am trying to read the properties from a property file into my parent `pom.xml`. From there I need to put the read properties to the variables defined in my html file.

Code for including properties file :

```
  <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <!-- Associate the read-project-properties goal with the initialize phase, to read the properties file. -->
              <execution>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <files>
                    <file>${basedir}/build.${build.env}.properties</file>
                  </files>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>


            <!-- Maven War file generator plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                <include>**/*.css</include>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                                <include>**/*.html</include>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
           </plugins>
```

I was using ant before and there I was using `filterset` tag to apply these filters like

code in build.xml:

```
   <filterset>
            <filter token="HOSTNAME_PREFIX" value="${hostname.prefix}"/>
            <filter token="MIN_SUFFIX" value="${min.suffix}"/>
            <filter token="APP_VERSION" value="${build.app.version}"/>
        </filterset>
```

but I dont know how to achieve the same thing using maven.

the code to be replaced in index.html is :

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="@HOSTNAME_PREFIX@appimages/app-logo.ico" type="image/png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@HOSTNAME_PREFIX@css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0@MIN_SUFFIX@.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple resource elements in the war plugin config to achieve this, one for the resources you want to filter, and one for the resources you don't.

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
            <include>**/*.css</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.html</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

Also, I would suggest not putting your resources in `/src/main/java`; that directory is for Java files, which resources are not.

Comment: thanks for you answer. just wanted to know how will this plug the values of the required properties. As I mentioned in the example of ant..

Comment: There are multiple ways to supply property values.  Please check the [Maven POM reference docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).  You may also find the [resource filtering overview](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_filter_resource_files) helpful.

Comment: it didnt solve my purpose of replacing the tokens in index.html. The solution mentioned in the references is to create a separate filter.properties file and then pass values from it to application.properties file but that solution is not working for me

Comment: application.properties is simply the example they are using in the docs.  You are not required to use that file.  If you used a separate filter.properties file, did you also add the `<filters>` element to the `<build>` as shown in the example?  The other document I linked mentions other ways to define properties in the POM (`<properties>` block) if you don't want them in a separate file.

Comment: yeah I added the requred file in the <filters>. actually I have 3 properties files, out of them I load 1 file depending on the environment to build for. so what I want to do is to read the properties from that property file and replace the filters set in html code as I have mentioned in the question. The problem is that I am able to read the properties from the properties file but not being able to apply it to the html file..